# set date in datepicker

Tags: android, datepicker

I have a problem with datepicker Android. I trying to set datePicker with value in textView, but it doesn't work.

This is my code :

```
tv_title.setText("DETAIL PELANGGAN");
            pelanggan = (Pelanggan) 

    getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("plgan");
                pos = (Integer) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("pos");

                et_ktp.setText(pelanggan.getKtp());
                et_name.setText(pelanggan.getNama());
                et_address.setText(pelanggan.getAlamat());
                et_ibuKandung.setText(pelanggan.getIbu_kandung());
                tv_birthdate.setText(pelanggan.getTgl_lahir());
                addListenerOnButton();

                arDate = pelanggan.getTgl_lahir().split("-");
                Log.d("Tanggal", arDate[2]+"Das");

                if(arDate[2].length() > 4)
                {
                    arDate[2] = arDate[2].substring(0,4);
                }

                Log.d("Tanggal", arDate[2]+"Ar");
                setCustomerCurrentBirthdate();
```

and for void setCustomerCurrentBirthdate() is

```
public void setCustomerCurrentBirthdate()
    {
        datePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.dp_birthdate);

        year = Integer.parseInt(arDate[2]);
        month = Integer.parseInt(arDate[1])+1;
        day = Integer.parseInt(arDate[0]);

        datePicker.init(year, month, day, null);
    }
```

And for xml of datePicker is

```
<DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/dp_birthdate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textColor="#0055FF"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp">
    </DatePicker>
```

The problem is when datePicker appear, it show current date, not date that I set in setCustomerCurrentBirthdate().
Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

You already init the `DatePicker` in XML, and it is automatically set with current date.

Use `datePicker.updateDate(year, month, day)` instead of `datePicker.init(year, month, day, null)` before changing visibility.

Comment: Owhm, thank you for your help, mate. But sorry it still not work till I make new method for that.

Answer (score -1):

Since I have an advice from @Nicholas Tee, I have an idea to make some void to set my datePicker.

```
public void addListenerOnButtonCustomerBirth(final String[] arDate)
    {

        tv_birthdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                year = Integer.parseInt(arDate[2]);
                month = Integer.parseInt(arDate[1])-1;
                day = Integer.parseInt(arDate[0]);

                showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
            }
        });
    }
```

and for call the void, this is the way to use it

```
arDate = tv_birthdate.getText().toString().split("-");

            if(arDate[2].length() > 4)
            {
                arDate[2] = arDate[2].substring(0,4);
            }

            addListenerOnButtonCustomerBirth(arDate);
```

Indeed it's too amateur, but however it works. I will be glad if it can help other